# Using UIActivityViewController to share content on non-official Twitter clients?

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, uiactivityviewcontroller

I want to share some contents from my application on `Twitter` and I wonder if there is a way to handle the unofficial `Twitter` clients like `Tweetbot` or `Twitterrific` by using `UIActivityViewController` ?

Indeed, these applications don't appear on the list when I launch the share action.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're trying to share, but if it's text or something Twitter can handle, other Twitter apps should be able to do it as well, as long as the developers created a Share Extension. By default (I think), third-party Share Extensions are disabled. Scroll to the right of the Activity View and tap on the "More" button. You'll see all available Share Extensions there.

Comment: It seems like Twitterific doesn't provide a Share Extension, but a friend of mine said Tweetbot is providing a Share Extension. When you want to share something via `UIActivityViewController`, you can't do anything to support apps without such an extension.

Comment: I don't know whether this is useful, but [here's a list](http://support.iconfactory.com/kb/twitterrific/url-schemes-in-twitterrific-5) of URL schemes you can use to do things in Twitterific.